# TCP Connect takes X100 longer than ping

Tags: java, networking, tomcat, tcp

I have a java process on machine A communicating with a Tomcat on machine B via TCP. The TCP connect (just the syn-syn/ack exchange) takes on the order of 100 ms consistently, while a ping request takes 1 ms (the serves are on the same LAN).

1. What could cause the increased delay in establishing a TCP connection?
2. How do I optimize it?

Note that:

- This is not yet a 3-way-handshake, I'm measuring only the syn/syn-ack exchange.
- The server is a very strong machine and not under load at all.
- The connect request is to an IP, not a hostname, so no DNS lookup is involved. In fact, this is not relevant since I'm measuring the time sine the SYN left machine A.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to other ports on the same machine? That way you could work out whether it's the networking stack or Tomcat.

Comment: Even if using IPs you might way for the B endpoint to try and resolve the reverse of the IP. Does adding a name for A in B's local DNS (/etc/hosts) change anything?

Comment: diciu - this is not how TCP works. A SYN/ACK will not do DNS resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is not in the client or server themselves. I took two packet dumps on the client and server:

1. The client sees a 100-150 ms time difference between seeing the SYN and receiving the SYN/ACK.
2. The server sees only a 20 ms time difference between receiving the SYN and sending the SYN/ACK.

Ergo, the problem must be in some intermediate layer (router/firewall/whatnot).

Comment: Hmm check my answer on SO for a laugh.

http://serverfault.com/questions/92167/why-am-i-getting-long-tcp-connect-latency-on-connect-in-a-lan-over-a-cross/92546#92546